# MySQL Joins with "tolerance"

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to add some kind of "tolerance" to the following query. That means, that I can specify a value which expresses how many of the four (sub) selects return rows > 0. So if this value is 2, I only want to join these two tables. Is there a way to realize that?

```
SELECT distinct(user_id) FROM 

(SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t2
ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t3
ON t1.user_id=t3.user_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t4
ON t1.user_id=t4.user_id
```

**EDIT:** 
Possible results for each sub-query could be as follows:

```
t1 t2 t3 t4
 0  0  0
 1  1  1  1
 2  2  2  2
 3        3
```

If all these sub results are joined it would result in: 1,2.
If I add a tolerance factor of 1, I want my result to be 0,1,2 as only one "0" is missing. If the factor was 2, the result would be 0,1,2,3 because two "3" and one "0" are missing. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Do you want this for performance reasons (i.e. eliminate the overhead of the lookups on the extra tables) or for business logic reasons (i.e. count how many of the lookups succeeds and behave differently)?

Comment: It's for business logic reasons (to do some experiments with my data sets).

Comment: In the WHERE clause are different arguments but all selects are made from the same table (I had to correct this in my example above).

Comment: So basically you want nothing more than a self-modifying statement, that also already knows how many results the individual parts will return, before the respective queries have even been made ... So you are looking for a time-machine plugin for MySQL?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I've added a small example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to union all sub selects and count them like follows:

```
SELECT distinct(user_id), sum(t) as tolerance FROM (

SELECT user_id, 1 as t FROM table1 WHERE ... GROUP BY...
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 1 as t FROM table1 WHERE ... GROUP BY...
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 1 as t FROM table1 WHERE ... GROUP BY...
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 1 as t FROM table1 WHERE ... GROUP BY...

) as x GROUP BY ... HAVING tolerance <= 2
```

Then you can specify how many sub selects should return something (here: 2).

Answer (score 0):

If i had understood your problem, you can add a variable in your sub-select and filter after:

```
SELECT distinct(user_id) FROM     
(SELECT user_id, 1 as table_from FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, 2 as table_from FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t2
ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, 3 as table_from FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t3
ON t1.user_id=t3.user_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, 4 as table_from FROM table1 WHERE ...) as t4
ON t1.user_id=t4.user_id
WHERE table_from <= 2;
```

Comment: I think this would still do all joins and pick only the user_ids from t1 and t2 in the end.